# Run scala test "Spec" file programmatically

Tags: scala, unit-testing, integration-testing

I have a `Spec` subclass B which extends another `Spec` A and I want the tests in B to run too whenever I run the A test file.
(A and B are in the same file)

Is there a way I can programmatically do this by adding some scala code in class A.
Like within A, can I instantiate the `Spec` class somehow and then call `runTests` on that object ?

Comment: Re-ask this question with some code and more detail I think. Also if B extends A, A shouldn't know about B, that wouldn't make sense. May as well merge B into A then.

Comment: don't extend spec classes

Answer (score 0):

here you go:

```
class SpecB extends Specification {
    new SpecA() // it is a fragment and will be executed within the other
    // more logic here
}


// if you're NOT in a Spec, this might be helpful:

implicit val app: Application = play.api.test.Helpers.baseApplicationBuilder.build
Play.start(app)
org.specs2.runner.TextRunner.run(
  new org.specs2.mutable.Specification {
       1 === 1
       // and app.injector stuff e.g. 
  }
}.flush
```

Comment: this works in unit test parameterized contexts for example